# angular array loop using ngFor get array count and display the value

Tags: javascript, angular

I showed data using below angular functions

```
availableLockers = [
    {
      "lockerCode": "L01",
      "allocStatus": "alloc"
    },
    {
      "lockerCode": "L02",
      "allocStatus": "un-alloc"
    },
    {
      "lockerCode": "L03",
      "allocStatus": "un-alloc"
    },
    {
      "lockerCode": "L04",
      "allocStatus": "temp-alloc"
    }, {
      "lockerCode": "L05",
      "allocStatus": "alloc"
},]
```

I am using bellow html

```html
<div *ngFor="let locker of availableLockers let i=index;">{{locker.lockerCode}} </div>
```

The above code is working well. currently I need do display count of each status.
Ex: how many lockers with "alloc" status, how many lockers with "temp-alloc" status.

Comment: What do you mean by count ? Please clarify

Comment: how many lockers with "alloc" status, how many lockers with "temp-alloc" status

Comment: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 31 in [ {{ availableLockers.filter(obj => allocStatus === "un-alloc").length

Comment: first thing that pops up in my mind is to loop the array and count statuses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with filter(),

```
let availableLockers = [
  {
    lockerCode: 'L01',
    allocStatus: 'alloc'
  },
  {
    lockerCode: 'L02',
    allocStatus: 'un-alloc'
  },
  {
    lockerCode: 'L03',
    allocStatus: 'un-alloc'
  },
  {
    lockerCode: 'L04',
    allocStatus: 'temp-alloc'
  },
  {
    lockerCode: 'L05',
    allocStatus: 'alloc'
  }
];

function checkStatus(status) {
  let data = availableLockers.filter(locker => locker.allocStatus === status);
  return data.length;
}

console.log(checkStatus('alloc'));
console.log(checkStatus('un-alloc'));
console.log(checkStatus('temp-alloc'));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to create a dictionary for the count of each `allocStatus` using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

**and then use it where ever you want with O(1) time complexity**

```js
availableLockers = [
  {
    lockerCode: "L01",
    allocStatus: "alloc",
  },
  {
    lockerCode: "L02",
    allocStatus: "un-alloc",
  },
  {
    lockerCode: "L03",
    allocStatus: "un-alloc",
  },
  {
    lockerCode: "L04",
    allocStatus: "temp-alloc",
  },
  {
    lockerCode: "L05",
    allocStatus: "alloc",
  },
];

const dict = availableLockers.reduce((acc, { allocStatus }) => {
  if (acc[allocStatus]) ++acc[allocStatus];
  else acc[allocStatus] = 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(dict["alloc"]);
console.log(dict["un-alloc"]);
console.log(dict["temp-alloc"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Html File**

```
<div *ngFor="let locker of availableLockers; let i=index;">
 {{locker.lockerCode}}
</div>
<div>{{alloc}}</div>
<div>{{unAlloc}}</div>
<div>{{tempAlloc}}</div>
```

**In TS file**

```
    alloc:number = 0;
    unAlloc:number = 0;
    tempAlloc:number = 0;
    
    ngOnInit(){
     availableLockers.forEach((value)=>{
     if (value['allocStatus']=='alloc'){
        alloc++}
     elseif (value['allocStatus']=='un-alloc'){
            unAlloc++}
     elseif (value['allocStatus']=='temp-alloc'){
            tempAlloc++}

     })
     }
```

Comment: My earlier code was completely wrong sorry for that, edited it and this should work now.